# How to project to oblique Mollweide

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj

I know how to produce a map with the Mollweide projection, both using QGIS and R (I'm most interested in doing all of this in R). The proj4string that I've used in R is `+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

But I am interested in producing a map using what I've seen called the Mollweide oblique projection, or the Atlantis projection, or alternatively the "Hammer map". [See here for examples.](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjObl/projObl.html)

I'm not quite sure where to start, though.

Does this involve adjusting some of the parameters in the above Mollweide proj4string?

For starters, here is how I get a map in Mollweide projection:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

mollCRS <- CRS('+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')

mollMap <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, mollCRS)
```