# Custom Mollweide Projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to have a custom Mollweide Projection (from ESPG: 53009) in QGis, that has it's center points somwhere else than `0,0` degrees. Let's say at `-10,-60` degrees.

Here is the wkt for the epsg:53009 one:

```
PROJCRS["Sphere_Mollweide",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Unknown datum based upon the Authalic Sphere",
        DATUM["Not specified (based on Authalic Sphere)",
            ELLIPSOID["Sphere",6371000,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["Sphere_Mollweide",
        METHOD["Mollweide"],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["ESRI",53009]]
```

Which parameters do I tweak and how?

I guess it must be the `PRIMEM` or the `Longitude of natural origin` but I don't know where to change the latitude.

Just changing the natural origin parameter to `-60`resulted in this:
[image]

Comment: Not the PRIMEN but the Longitude of natural origin parameter. But the projection is not oblique so you can't change the latitude of the center. If you really need to make such a map you should rotate the original data (as if you rotated the continents, leaving for example Antarctica outside the south pole) the angle you want, and then apply the projection.

Comment: Related unanswered https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289428/how-to-project-to-oblique-mollweide

Comment: Here an answer about "rotate the world instead of the projection": https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414669/133276. The dateline issues are another problem. It is related in the way polygon geometries are stored and rendered. I only found a handmade workaround in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/347157/133276.